# Vanilla JavaScript Tabs Using if-else Statements inside forEach Instead of a for Loop

Tags: javascript

I created tabs using Vanilla JavaScript but am struggling a little bit to understand why I can't replace a `for` loop with a `forEach` loop that is inside of a `onTabSelectorClick` function.

I tried replacing the `for` loop below:

```
   for(i; i < tabSelector.length; i++) {
      if(tabSelectorSelected.getAttribute('data-id') === tabContent[i].getAttribute('data-id')) {
         tabContent[i].classList.add('tab-content-active');
      } else {
         tabSelector[i].classList.remove('active-tab-selector');
         tabContent[i].classList.remove('tab-content-active');
      }
    }
```

With this `forEach` loop and it doesn't work:

```
tabSelector.forEach(function(singleTabSelector, i) {
  if(singleTabSelector.getAttribute('data-id') === tabContent[i].getAttribute('data-id')) {
     tabContent[i].classList.add('tab-content-active');
  } else {
     singleTabSelector.classList.remove('active-tab-selector');
     tabContent[i].classList.remove('tab-content-active');
  }
});
```

*Is it not possible to use condition **if-else** statements inside `forEach` loops when interating over an array-like object?*

```js
var tabSelector = document.querySelectorAll('#tab-selectors > li');
var tabContent = document.querySelectorAll('#tab-contents > div');

tabSelector.forEach(function(singleTabSelector, i) {
  singleTabSelector.setAttribute('data-id', i);
  tabContent[i].setAttribute('data-id', i);
});

function onTabSelectorClick(e) {
  var tabSelectorSelected = e.target;
  
  if(!tabSelectorSelected.classList.contains('active-tab-selector')) {
    var i = 0;
    for(i; i < tabSelector.length; i++) {
      if(tabSelectorSelected.getAttribute('data-id') === tabContent[i].getAttribute('data-id')) {
         tabContent[i].classList.add('tab-content-active');
      } else {
         tabSelector[i].classList.remove('active-tab-selector');
         tabContent[i].classList.remove('tab-content-active');
      }
    }
    
    tabSelectorSelected.classList.add('active-tab-selector')
  }
}

tabSelector.forEach(function(tabSelector) {
  tabSelector.addEventListener('click', onTabSelectorClick);
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#tab-selectors {
  display: inline-block;
}

#tab-selectors > li {
  padding: 10px;
}

#tab-selectors > .active-tab-selector {
  border: 1px solid #f00; 
}

#tab-content {
  display: inline-block;
}

#tab-contents > div {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  display: none;
}

#tab-contents > .tab-content-active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Accessible Tabs using Vanilla JavaScript</h1>
  <ul id="tab-selectors">
    <li class="active-tab-selector">Tab Selector 1</li>
    <li>Tab Selector 2</li>
    <li>Tab Selector 3</li>
  </ul>  
  
  <div class="break"><div>
  
  <div id="tab-contents">
    <div class="tab-content-active">
      Tab Content 1
    </div>  
    <div>
      Tab Content 2
    </div>  
    <div>
      Tab Content 3
    </div>        
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use a `for of` loop on Elements, not `.forEach`. `for(let e of elementCollection){ /* e is element */ }`

Comment: I don't want to use ES6 (**or of** loop). I forgot to mention that.

I also want an explanation of why I can't use if-else statements inside the **forEach** loop I mentioned in my original question.

Comment: Those two loop bodies are not exactly the same; typo, or did you get something wrong?

Comment: @StackSlave: `forEach` _is_ supported for `NodeList`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach

Comment: Please try to use the code in the **code pen** I created (see link below) and replace the **for** loop mentioned with the **forEach** loop mentioned.

I'm once again trying to understand where I can't use if-else statements inside the **forEach** loop mentioned.

https://codepen.io/hollyw00d/pen/JjYJWjG

Comment: @Jacob, comment removed. You are correct. It didn't used to work, and still doesn't in older Browsers and IE *(but who cares?)*. I still think `for of ` is the way to go, since you can't return anything from within `.forEach`.

Comment: @risingPhoenix1979: it works for me _if I fix your loop code to be the same_. Look closely; what you posted before and after don't match.

Comment: @Jacob
Can you please post the correct `forEach` code, in place of the `for` code?

Comment: Here's my code pen where you see it working. Will add an answer. https://codepen.io/dullreferenceexception/pen/rNOzvvN

Comment: in your second block of code, should if (singleTabSelector... to if (tabSelectorSelected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing special about how if statements works within a loop or a function. Your issue looks like a mere logic issue. Here's the before logic, in the for loop:

```
if(tabSelectorSelected.getAttribute('data-id') === tabContent[i].getAttribute('data-id')) {
  tabContent[i].classList.add('tab-content-active');
} else {
  tabSelector[i].classList.remove('active-tab-selector');
  tabContent[i].classList.remove('tab-content-active');
}
```

...and here was your after logic using the `.forEach`:

```
if(singleTabSelector.getAttribute('data-id') === tabContent[i].getAttribute('data-id')) {
  tabContent[i].classList.add('tab-content-active');
} else {
  singleTabSelector.classList.remove('active-tab-selector');
  tabContent[i].classList.remove('tab-content-active');
}
```

...which is equivalent to this (hopefully this makes comparing the two easier):

```
if(tabSelector[i].getAttribute('data-id') === tabContent[i].getAttribute('data-id')) {
  tabContent[i].classList.add('tab-content-active');
} else {
  tabSelector[i].classList.remove('active-tab-selector');
  tabContent[i].classList.remove('tab-content-active');
}
```

Notice how between those two loops, in the second one you changed the element you're checking the `data-id` on from being the `tabSelectorSelected` to the `singleTabSelector` which is the `tabSelector` item you're looping over. The two pieces of code are not equivalent.

In the original code, you're comparing the ID of the selected tab with the ID of the tab content. In the second you're comparing the tab selector *within the loop* with the content element at the same index, so in all cases they'll have a matching `data-id` attribute.

Comment: Thanks @Jacob for the before and after code. That's just what I needed. I marked your answer as correct and updated my **Code Pen**: https://codepen.io/hollyw00d/pen/JjYJWjG